# Pimcore 4 extending Document/Page

Tags: php, pimcore

Again I am having trouble getting the class mappings to work in Pimcore 4. This time I want to extend the document page class. This used to work without problems in older versions, but now I cannot get it working.

I copied this example in classmap.php from classmap.example.php:

website/config/classmap.php:

```
return [

    "Document\\Page" => "Website\\Model\\Document\\Page",
]
```

website/models/Website/Model/Document/Page.php:

```
namespace Website\Model;
use Pimcore\Model\Document; 

class Page extends Document\Page {

    public function getPublicPath() {
        return $this->getFullPath();
    }
}
```

The expected result is that I can call getPublicPath() on every document\page object. But this is not working. Instead I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method getPublicPath in class Pimcore\Model\Document\Page
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace declaration is wrong. It should be:

```
namespace Website\Model\Document;
```

So the whole class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Website\Model\Document;
use Pimcore\Model\Document;

class Page extends Document\Page {

    public function getPublicPath() {
        return $this->getFullPath();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to clear the cache after updating your code!